# Comparators in std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, heap, priority-queue

Is there a reason that the `std::priority_queue`'s constructor accepts a comparator by constant reference? What if the comparator goes out of scope?

I was thinking about this in the context of possibly moving the comparator as @LightnessRacesInOrbit pointed out!

I am sorry if there has already been a post about this.  I have not been able to find it!

Comment: Excellent question. I've never thought about this.

Comment: Your statement about lambdas doesn't make much sense. Lambdas can be copied...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have never actually thought about this before, and the const-ref indeed is a bit misleading. However, the function signature was thought up before move semantics came along and it became vogue to accept everything by value. Indeed, the comparator is copied!

> `[C++14: 23.6.4.1/4]:` *Effects:* Initializes `comp` with `x` and `c` with `y` (copy constructing or move constructing as appropriate); calls `c.insert(c.end(), first, last);` and finally calls `make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp).`

Lambdas are not copy-assignable, but they *are* copy-constructible, so there is no problem here.

> `[C++14: 5.1.2/20]:` The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator. It has an implicitly-declared copy constructor (12.8) and may have an implicitly-declared move constructor (12.8). *[..]*

Does this prevent move-construction of the comparator itself? Yes, it does. I'm going to assume that this convention, of taking the comparator by const-ref then copying it, stems from the STL days, way before move semantics. I imagine it wasn't seriously considered to add overloads to take the comparator by value because that adds complexity and you shouldn't have a complex, move-enhancible comparator in the first place (give them state, sure, but not *too much*). Still, this *may* be worth raising with the committee if you can come up with a solid use case for moving a comparator.

Comment: Makes me think about why there isn't a move constructor that moves the comparator!

Comment: @Curious: If your comparator has a move constructor then it will be invoked!!

Comment: Hmmmm.. I just checked. That is true.  I feel like it would be more clear if a rvalue constructor was provided!

Comment: @Curious: That's a fair point, actually — that wording is quite misleading and I misinterpreted it. Only the `Container` can be move constructed. In both ctors the `Comparator` is taken by const ref so move constructing is in fact impossible. I guess nobody cares because comparators are supposed to have only very minimal state if any at all. But you might consider proposing a new ctor overload with the committee.

Comment: @Curious: I've added a bit of writing to address this.

Comment: Whoaaaa that would be fancy.  How does one put forth such a legendary proposal?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't go out of scope -- it is copy constructed into the container.  The description on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) states:

```
explicit priority_queue( const Compare& compare = Compare(),
                         const Container& cont = Container() );
```

> Copy-constructs the underlying container c with the contents of cont. Copy-constructs the comparison functor comp with the contents of compare. Calls std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp). This is also the default constructor.

There are various other forms of the constructor, but in all cases the internal comparator is either copy- or move-constructed from the one supplied.

Comment: Well we usually pass lambdas into functions that take their `Callable` by value so I'd be astounded to hear that they're not supposed to be copyable. Can you provide any evidence for this claim?

Answer (score 4):

`std::priority_queue`'s constructor makes a copy of the comparator provided, so it's not a problem if it goes out of scope.

You can use a lambda as comparator either by using `std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)>` as comparator type, or directly:

```
auto comp = [](int x, int y) { return x > y; };
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(comp)> q(comp);
```

You can facilitate this with a helper function:

```
template<typename T, typename Compare>
auto make_priority_queue(Compare&& comp) {
    return std::priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>, Compare>(std::forward<Compare>(comp));
}

int main() {
    auto q = make_priority_queue<int>([](int x, int y) { return x > y; });
}
```

Comment: But then how can lambdas be used?

Comment: @Curious: They can be copied too.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was under the impression that they cannot be copied and have default copy constructors removed? Could you provide an example where you can successfully do this?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about my doubt.  I have updated my question